# Is traffic between applications on the same azure website charged?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Let's assume the following scenario:

1 website on hostname http://test.azurewebsites.com with 2 virtual directories (applications) (Test1 & Test2)

if we make a call from inside the codebase of http://test.azurewebsites.com/Test1 towords a webservice hosted on http://test.azurewebsites.com/Test2

- are we charged for the traffic
- will it run through the load balancer or always on the same machine?

Answer (score 2):

The request will run through the load balancer, since the request is going to the same data-center it will not incur cost.

Comment: Can you back up that statement with links to documentation?

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/ *Is data transfer between Azure services located within the same region charged?
No. For example, an Azure SQL database in the same region will not have any additional data transfer costs.*